# Lenovo Y410 restore grub

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have an old Lenovo Y410 Centrino Duo core. I have triple boot (no UEFI) windows xp, windows vista, linux partition.
I tried to install Lubuntu, as Xubuntu gave me desktop problems. There was an error with the install.
So, I thought to re-format the linux partition, before installing Lubuntu.
I forgot that grub2 has config files on this partition?
Now I cannot boot into any live drive (rescatux, plop boot manager, parted magic etc.).
The machine boots up into "grub rescue>".
And says "error file '/boot/ grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found".
How can I fix this? Does grub have an entry in the MBR - how to fix?

Comment: you can always boot into live usb because it uses it's own bootloader ; just enter the bios and change boot order {put usb drive first} and then try

Comment: @Madhubala It does not. It always gives me that error.

Comment: download a ubunu iso and create a bootable usb using rufus; also attach some images of your bios

Comment: OK, the live usb finally worked. Installed Lubuntu.  Grub is restored and it sees the windows partitions. I'm good. Thanks!